# Can I use multiple .ebignore files in nested directories, like I can with .gitignore files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to establish if I can use mulitple `.ebignore` files in nested directories, or if the correct approach is to use a single `.ebignore` file in the root of my project.

for example:

```
/.ebignore               # Some generic rules in here
/directory/.ebignore     # Some rules specific to this directory in here
```

The [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore) refer to the `.ebignore` file in the singluar, never plural:

> You can tell the EB CLI to ignore certain files in your project
>   directory with a .ebignore file. This file works like a .gitignore.
>   When you deploy your project directory to Elastic Beanstalk and create
>   a new application version, the EB CLI will not include files specified
>   by the .ebignore in the source bundle that it creates.

So can I use multiple `.ebignore` files?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use multiple `.ebignore`s. In this sense, it is not like `.gitignore`, so the statement from the documentation is not precise.